# What's the difference between List<Object> and List<?>

Tags: java

Before are all you burn me alive, I must say that I have googling this question many times and I still can't understand the difference between List<Object> and List<?>

All books I've read say that *in Java every class is implicitly a subclass of Object*.

However I saw [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/unboundedWildcards.html) the follwing code:

```
public static void printList(List<Object> list) {
    for (Object elem : list)
        System.out.println(elem + " ");
    System.out.println();
}
```

This code is wrong (intentionally for educational purposes) and according to the author the reason is:

*[...] prints only a list of Object instances; it cannot print **List<Integer>, List<String>, List<Double>**, and so on, because **they are not subtypes of List<Object>***

The solution is:

```
public static void printList(List<?> list) {
    for (Object elem: list)
        System.out.print(elem + " ");
    System.out.println();
}
```

As you can see, the only difference is the first line:

```
public static void printList(List<Object> list) {
public static void printList(List<?> list) {
```

This is the reason of my question: What's the difference between List<Object> and List<?>   ?

After all is *Object* superclass of everything or not?

If someone can help me with a simple explanation (I'm new with Java) I'll appreciate.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Explanation:

? is a "wildcard". You can use it in different ways:

unbounded wildcard:

```
?
```

wildcard with upper bound:

```
? extends Object (or another class)
```

wildcard with lower bound

```
? super Object (or another class)
```

### Examples:

```
List <?> list;
```

you can assign to `list` any List with any type parameter.

```
List<? extends Number> list;
```

you can assign to list any List with a type parameter Number (or Integer, Float, ecc)

```
List<? super Integer> list;
```

you can assign to list any List with a type parameter Integer, or a type in the type gerarchy of Integer(Number,Comparable, Serializable, Object ...)

### Summary:

So the declaration

```
List<Object> list;
```

is similar to

```
List<? super Object> list;
```

because you can assign to "list" only a List of Objects; then you can use the list in this way:

```
    list = new ArrayList<Object>();
    list.add(new String(""));
    list.add(new Integer(3));
```

Answer (score 9):

One of the major differences is how you can modify the lists. The following works well

```
List<Object> l1;
l1.add(new Object()); // OK
```

while the second case produces a compilation error.

```
List<?> l2;
l2.add(new Object()); // Compile error
```

The reasons for that I think has been debated a few times on the site already. In short,`<?>` means **a** (as in *one*) **specific** yet *unknown* type. Since that type is not known compile-time, you're not allowed to modify the list.

Answer (score 9):

That `String` is a subtype of `Object` does not mean that `List<String>` is a subtype of `List<Object>`. If it were, the following code would compile:

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Object> objects = strings;
objects.add((Integer) 1);
strings.get(0).charAt(0); // but the Integer 1 does not have a charAt method ...
```

Therefore, `List<String>` is not a subtype of `List<Object>`.

Both `List<String>` and `List<Object>` are subtypes of `List<?>`. But because `List<?>` is the more general type, you can't know what type the add method takes:

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
List<?> objects = strings;
objects.add((Integer) 1); // does not compile
```

Answer (score 2):

You can basically use both version in similar ways. However, there is one big difference. Let's declare the following:

```
List<Object> list1 = new ArrayList<Object>();
List<?> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Now, let's try the code below:

```
list1.add("");// this works fine
list2.add("");// this one issues a compile error
```

Someone could ask why this. This is because in `List<Object>`, the code tells you that you have `Object` or subtypes there, but in `List<?>` you could have the same thing but you don't know exactly what. Someone could add `String` or `Double` and then try to read and cast to `Integer`. But again, it is not possible.

There may be other differences that I don't remember about now.

Answer (score 2):

Object is the superclass of String but List<Object> is not the superclass of List<String>.  If it were, this would be a problem:

```
List<String> strings = ...
addObject(strings);
...
void addObjects(List<Object> objects) {
    objects.add(new Object());
}
```

Now strings contains an element that isn't a String.

Answer (score 2):

> This code is wrong (intentionally for educational purposes) and according to the author the reason is:
>
> [...] prints only a list of Object instances; it cannot print
>   List, List, List, and so on, because they are
>   not subtypes of List

This is because parameterized types are **invariant**, for instance for the classes X and Y, `List<X>` is neither a subtype nor a supertype of `List<Y>`.

The difference resides in that the **unbounded wildcard type** `?` means that the type is unknown and you can´t assume anything about it. A `List<?>` is type safe, you can´t put any element other than `null` in it and you can´t assume anything about the type of the object it contains.

`List<Object>` obviously means that the List can contain objects of any type.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void main(String args[]){

   List<? super Object> list=new ArrayList<>();
   list.add("A");//works

   List<Object> list1=new ArrayList<>();
   list1.add("B");//works
   
   List<?> list2=new ArrayList<>();
   list2.add("11");//compile time error;
   
   List<? extends Object> list4=new ArrayList<>();
   list4.add("123");//compile Time error
}
```

List< ? extend Object>  & List< ? > doesn't allow to add anything follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13993745/add-strings-through-use-of-generic-extends-causes-compiler-error/13993770#13993770) to know the reason. But on the other hand List< ? super Object> allows to add values to List because the problem in the link provided doesn't exists .